# How do I write underline text in text file or in Python?

Tags: python

I have tried the following:

```
test = 'test_underline.txt'

out_file = open(test,'w')

START = '\033[4m'

END = '\033[0m'

t = START + 'This is my underline string.' + END

print(t)

out_file.write(t)

out_file.close()
```

I am getting the correct output in command line,but in text file i am getting like this :

```
"[4mThis is my underline string.[0m"
```

Comment: Have you ever seen a text file with underlined text?

Comment: Underlining is a property of how the characters are represented on a screen or other display device, not a property of the characters themselves.  There is an ASCII value for the character "A" but no ASCII value for an "underlined A".

Answer (score 0):

`START = '\033[4m'
END = '\033[0m'`

It's format correct to bash. If you see response `cat test_underline.txt` you get underline text

Comment: Thank you for the response.....
But i want to add underline in my pdf file of number of question related to   apostrophes,so for that i am converting txt file to pdf.
How can i get that ?

Comment: @VikasBhargav, you should [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43534869/edit) title and text to explain you are trying to do this in a PDF.